# How to get ϱ and ɔ working with MinionPro

Tags: fonts, luatex, unicode

Using LuaLaTeX and MinionPro (the one from Adobe Reader), I apparently cannot print the characters ϱ and ɔ ("symbolic rho" and "open o"). This I find a bit strange in a professional font. Can that really be true?

If you want a MWE so badly, here it is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common}]{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}
    Hellɔ woϱld.
\end{document}
```

I know I can do something like

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ɔ}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{c}}
\newunicodechar{ϱ}{ρ}
```

but is that really the way to do it? I especially don't like the first one. And the second one changes from one version of rho to another, which I would have liked to avoid.

Comment: Thanks for the MWE (yeah, we always need it... Would be even better with `article` class and no font options). I do not have this font. Please try `\symbol{"03F1}\symbol{"0254}`. If there is nothing appearing, I would say, those symbols are not in Minion Pro.

Comment: Nothing appearing, unfortunately.

Comment: Neither of the is a 'common' symbol (the rho here isn't the usual lower case Greek letter): it would not surprise me at all if they are lacking. A definitive check can be made using a font editor if you have access to the font files (I don't).

Comment: On the type tester of this page: https://typekit.com/fonts/minion-pro it looks like they are existing. What did you mean by "from Adobe Reader"? Did you buy the font package or do you use something shipped with Adobe Reader. Could be a minor bundle. If you are on Windows, install NexusFont and have a look on the files you have.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a (perhaps limited?) copy of MinionPro that comes with Adobe Reader.

Comment: store1.adobe doesn't show the symbols.

Comment: https://typekit.com/fonts/minion-pro does if I copy it into the "type tester". This shows that the characters do indeed exist in the *paid* version of the font.

Comment: @Gaussler At least to me, they are in a different font. I mean, it's obvious those characters are not from Minion Pro.

Comment: I have the paid version, and these characters do not exist in this font (checked with Nexus Font).

Comment: @Gaussler The font store of Adobe shows that the glyphs are non existing, if you zoom in on the *typekit* output you linked above, you will notice that the glyphs are taken from another font.

Comment: @Gaussler I suggest one solution here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224584/define-fallback-font-for-specific-unicode-characters-in-lualatex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MinionPro font that comes with Adobe Reader does not have these symbols:

[image][image]

In short, you can't use characters from a font that doesn't have those characters. This is therefore not a question about TeX, and you seem to acknowledge that in your question, asking if it "can really be true" that Adobe's MinionPro font doesn't have these symbols. I'm therefore voting to close this question.

Comment: My question *was* meant to be about TeX. For --- since I simply didn't believe that those characters were not a part of a font as compatible as MinionPro --- I assumed that the error occurred on the TeX level. This turned out not to be the case; but that I could not have known until I asked the question.

Comment: In short: What the answer is about is not necessarily the same as what the question is about.

Comment: @Gaussler There's no real disagreement between us, so I see no need to pursue this further. You suspected in your question that either: (1) the font you were using didn't have the characters you needed. I confirmed this. Or: (2) Something's up with TeX. But there's not. This doesn't mean that there was anything wrong with your question (closing a question doesn't imply that). It was closed because the problem doesn't have anything to do with TeX.