# Define fallback font for specific Unicode characters in LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, symbols, luatex, unicode

[This closed question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224529/how-to-get-%cf%b1-and-%c9%94-working-with-minionpro) prompts me to propose a more general question and a solution I don't think has been demonstrated here.

When compiling with LuaLaTeX and using Unicode input, how do you set up a fallback font for specific Unicode characters that are absent from the main font?

I would welcome other approaches or critiques of the one I demonstrate.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

We can define a command to switch to a fallback font using `fontspec`.

Then we can use `newunicodechar` to map the missing Unicode characters to a command that switched to the fallback font for those characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec, newunicodechar}
\setmainfont{PT Serif}
\newfontfamily{\fallbackfont}{Linux Libertine O}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textfallback}{\fallbackfont}
\newunicodechar{ɔ}{\textfallback{ɔ}}
\newunicodechar{ϱ}{\textfallback{ϱ}}

\begin{document}
Hellɔ woϱld.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Output of `pdffonts` showing that both fonts are used:

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
NUOAQT+PTSerif-Regular               CID TrueType      yes yes yes      4  0
UAEGUX+LinLibertineO                 CID Type 0C       yes yes yes      5  0
```

**EDIT:**

We could also define a general command for setting up missing characters.
It takes an optional argument which defaults to `\textfallback`, but a different font could be inserted in case an additional fallback font was needed.

```
\newcommand{\fallbackchar}[2][\textfallback]{%
    \newunicodechar{#2}{#1{#2}}%
}
\fallbackchar{ɔ}
\fallbackchar{ϱ}
```

Comment: `\DeclareTextFontCommand\textfallback{\fallbackfont}` is the *official* way of defining `\textfallback`.

Comment: @Manuel Where is this documented? I see `\DeclareTextFontCommand` used twice in the `fontspec` manual, but not explained.

Comment: LaTeS kernel, IIRC.

Comment: @Manuel Thank you for improving the answer! I found the command on line 3721 of `latex.ltx`. I edited the answer to use this.

Comment: I am wondering if this could be automated somehow, so that whenever `fontspec` stumbles upon a character that is not in the font, it prints that character with `\textfallback` instead.

Comment: @Gaussler This might interest you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53599/standard-cjk-fonts-for-latex

Comment: @Gaussler And this even more: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165665/detect-if-all-required-glyphs-are-available/171872#171872