# Versicle and response symbols

Tags: symbols

I want to properly typeset the [versicle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%84%A3) and [response](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%84%9F#English) symbols. The versicle symbol looks like this:

[image: versicle symbol]

and the response symbol is the same but with "R" instead of "V".

[The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) provides a solution which requires XeLaTeX and the Junicode font, but is there a way to properly typeset the symbols using pdfLaTeX (i.e. is there a package which provides the symbols)? If not, what is the best way to construct the symbols manually?

I managed to construct something that looks like a versicle with

```
\newcommand{\versicle}{$\mathbf{\not{\mkern -3mu \mathrm{V}}}$}
```

but I'm not skilled at constructing symbols and I know that's not right.

I'm open to using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX if necessary to properly typeset these symbols but I'd like to know if there is a good way to do it with pdfLaTeX.

---

An example of the use of these symbols can be found in, e.g., [Wikipedia's article on the *Tantum ergo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantum_ergo#English_translation):

[image: Example usage of versicle/response]

Comment: Are rthey symbols for maths relations, or binary relations?

Comment: @Bernard No, I used math mode simply so I could use `\not` for the slash. My code is very much a hack, just to demonstrate that I tried to make my own but lack the skill/knowledge to do it.

Comment: ℣ and ℟ are Unicode charaters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A poorman’s version:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\versicle}{\vers@resp{-0.1em}{V}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\response}{\vers@resp{0pt}{R}}

\newcommand{\vers@resp@sym}{\raisebox{0.2ex}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-20}{$\m@th\rceil$}}}

\newcommand{\vers@resp}[2]{%
  {\ooalign{\hidewidth\kern#1\vers@resp@sym\hidewidth\cr#2\cr}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\versicle

\response

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may need to fine tune the parameters for a different font.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a possibility with `stackengine`.

```
\documentclass[border = 6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\versicle}{\kern-0.25em \stackinset{r}{0.33ex}{c}{}{\rotatebox{-30}{\normalsize$\rceil$}}{V}}

\newcommand{\response}{\kern-0.25em\stackinset{r}{0.35ex}{c}{}{ \rotatebox{-30}{\normalsize$\rceil$}}{R}}

\begin{document}

 A \versicle B \quad C \response D 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks a lot better than mine, +1! The symbols aren't used in math mode, though, so I'd have `\versicle` and `\response` enter and exit math mode as part of the marco. I added an example of the use of the symbols to my question to better show the usage.

Comment: Beware the code used  some math kerning, so you'd have to convert it to ordinary kerning (and change the unit – mu is a unit specifically for math kerning.

Comment: I've updated my answer for text mode. The code is simpler. Please see if it's fine for you.

Comment: How did I miss this question? LOL!  +1 for `stackengine`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: it's my favourite tool to make new symbols out of other symbols…

Comment: This is pretty good. I tweaked your code a bit to make the symbols look a little more accurate, in my opinion (I mainly adjusted the argument to `\rotatebox` from `-30` to `-25`, which makes the slash look more parallel to the right side of the V). No big deal. One issue I found by accident while testing, though, is that the slash doesn't scale properly when I increase the font size (I only intend to use the normal font size but I tried to use a very large font size while testing to see the symbols better). @egreg's solution seems to scale properly. Can that be fixed with this solution?

Comment: Except a `\scalebox`, a priori, I don't see. Maybe`, if it's for a casual use, replace `\normalsize` in the fifth argument of `\stackinset`with something like `\large` or `\Large`. Could you post an example?

Comment: When I was testing I simply used `\Huge \versicle\ \response` in the document. I agree that I'd need to replace the `\normalsize` argument with whatever the current font size setting is. I'd like to automatically detect the current font size setting but I've been searching TeX.SE and I haven't found a way to do it. I guess the alternative would be to add an argument to the `\versicle` and `\response` commands to give it the desired font size setting (typically `\normalsize` but could be `\large` or whatever).

Comment: It's an idea. Maybe, an optional argument, defaulting to `\normalsize`. Or ask the automatic detection of the font size? I'm no LaTeX guru, and have no idea about this.

Comment: Yeah, it would have to be a separate question on how to automatically detect the font size. Even if you don't know the answer to that you certainly seem to be a LaTeX guru with 183k reputation! I've accepted egreg's solution since it scales automatically but thanks for your help (I've already upvoted your answer).

Answer (score 4):

℣ (U+2123) and ℟ (U+211F) are Unicode characters, so use a font that has these characters (e.g., Noto Serif):

```latex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{<name of font with these characters>}
```

Or you can specify a fallback font, where Nimbus Roman lacks ℣ and ℟, so we use Noto Serif's:

```latex
\usepackage{fontspec, newunicodechar} 
\setmainfont{Nimbus Roman}
\newfontfamily{\fallbackfont}{Noto Serif}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textfallback}{\fallbackfont}
\newunicodechar{℣}{\textfallback{℣}}
\newunicodechar{℟}{\textfallback{℟}}
```

<sup>courtesy: "[Define fallback font for specific Unicode characters in LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224585/36603)"</sup>

See page 297 of [*The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-letter.pdf) (5 May 2021 rev.).

Answer (score 3):

There is a very simple way to do that: using "gregorio" in LualaTex:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}%I like this font, but you can use another font.
\usepackage{gregoriosyms}    
\begin{document}

\Vbar

\Rbar

\end{document}
```

[image]