# How to use package is part of texlive-music for write V and R of Versicle and Response?

Tags: fonts, packages, music

I need **only** the traditional `V` and `R` characters for Versicle and Response. In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512191/163311) is recommended to use the `gregoriotex` package.

When trying to install it on Ubuntu, the message from TexLive tells me that another package called `texlive-music` was installed instead which.

Indeed, within [the music package texlive](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/groovy/+package/texlive-music) is `gregoriotex`, but I can't use it.

When I try to use that package with:

```
\usepackage{gregoriotex}
```

It gives me the error:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `luatexbase.sty' not found.
>
> Type X to quit or  to proceed, or enter new name. (Default
> extension: sty)
>
> Enter file name:  ! Emergency stop. <read *>
> l.32 \RequirePackage
> {luaotfload}%^^M
> *** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

How I can use that package or some other that allows me to do `V /` and `R /` in a simple way?