# Define fallback font for a large character set (e.g. Simplified Chinese)

Tags: fonts, luatex, chinese

I've been asked to integrate Chinese characters into a mainly-English LaTeX template.

Although I found different options, such as ctex, I stumbled with its integration (mainly because the documentation is only available in Chinese). As a result, the best workable solution I found was to set the font to one with an extensive enough character set (along the lines of `\setmainfont{NotoSansCJKjp}`).

Now there's a final hurdle: due to corporate restrictions, I must use a "normal" font for most of the document, so I have to switch back and forth among fonts. I can define a command to switch the font and ask the user to use it before every text in Chinese, but this feels error prone and cumbersome.

As a result, I'd like to define a "secondary font": if the character exists in the "normal" font, print it. Else, fall back to the secondary font. I've seen [questions like this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224584/define-fallback-font-for-specific-unicode-characters-in-lualatex), but an individual mapping of each Chinese character is unworkable, and I'm not sure it would even solve the problem.

So, the question is: is this possible, say, with `fontspec`? **Can I define a fallback font for a large subset of characters?**

Comment: are you using lualatex or xelatex?

Comment: Lualatex </EOM>